# Unable to access one computer (Win7) from another (Mac OSX) over a home network

Tags: networking, hostname

I am not able to even ping the local ip address of each of those computers. How can I go about fixing that issue? I am basically trying to host few servers from one of the boxes (Win 7) and be able to access it from the other computer (OSX).

I would need hostnames set up correctly, right?

Update:

ip addresses are 192.168.1.4 and 192.168.1.5 and subnet is 255.255.255.0 and they are set by DHCP.

Comment: What are the IP addresses and subnet masks of both machines? Are you setting them manually, or via DHCP?

Comment: IP's are 192.168.1.4 and 192.168.1.5 and the subnet masks are 255.255.255.0 for both. And yes they are set via DHCP. Is it supposed to be manual? (I updated original post w/ above info as well). Thanks for the reply, -Nick

Comment: No, that actually should be fine. Both are on the same subnet (which is *vital*), so we can rule out a large chunk of "misconfigured network" possibilities. Do both machines have internet access (assuming the network does)? Have you tried pinging from each to the other (is it failing in both directions)? Does either machine have a strong firewall active?

Comment: I do have a firewall on my MAC but it only blocks (or at least warns me) on outgoing requests. The other machine is an out of the box installation of win7. Both can access the web but I can't ping each other from each machine (Mac can't ping win7, win7 can't ping mac)

Answer (score 0):

try to ping the full network from your machines. With your network broadcast adress in your case :

ping 192.168.1.255

Then check your firewall setting on the mac it it in system preferences > security and deactivate for the test. For windows i don't have a machine here to tell you.
You can have a deny all and it should explain all your problems.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. It pings all 3 devices on my network. Next to the two other computers where it says 64 bytes returned from 192.168.1.xxx, it puts (DUP!)

Comment: Are you sure the icmp request are not filtered by your switch ??
Did you try with another service ?